# Microsoft Azure DNS Cache

Tags: azure, caching, dns, containers

I just started using Azure. I'm using containers. For each container, I gave a dns-name-label property. Then after few hours of Azure training, I dicided to delete all my containers. Any resource still exist.

I cannot create a new container using a dns-name-label which has been deleted.

```
The DNS name label 'xxx' in container group 'x' not available. Try using a different label.
```

I would prefer find a solution rather than change all my dns-name-label because I have an existing software configuration (really long) which is using all these dns-name-label.

Would someone have a solution please ?

I already tried few commands like `az cache list` or `az cache purge`.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that the DNS name still exists. Probably, it has not completely finished deleting the container group or the current DNS name is in use in another container group somewhere.

I can not reproduce your issue. You should use `az container delete --name MyContainerGroup --resource-group MyResourceGroup` to remove that container group then create your new container with the old DNS name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No container still exists : az container list
[]. The issue might be waiting 24 hours again. I won't have time. I'm going to change my software configuration.

Comment: could you try `az container delete` again?

Comment: As I deleted my resource-group after delete all my containers i can't acess again this command specifying my old resource-group name.

Comment: Can i do something with these resources ? "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"/"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers"

Comment: could you explain it? and if you have deleted that RG, could you check if that RG still exists on [Azure resources](https://resources.azure.com)?

Comment: I removed all my RG. I do not have any existing containers. I do not have any resource existing except one Microsoft.Storage and one Microsoft.Network (I do not think i created them).

Comment: It looks like not related to this issue. Could you try to run command `nslookup` your full dns name for old container to check if any response. Now try to `az container create` Is the original DNS name label error persisting?

Comment: Thanks for your help. No response. Error still persisting. I'm going to give up with this dns-name-label and change all my configuration.